# window.location.href doesn't work with a form submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm trying to create a voting compass where I'm attempting to submit a form and insert the answers to a database, and then take the user to a results page.  When I have a submit button, I'm able to successfully store the answers but the page just refreshes rather than taking them to the results page.

However, if I change the submit button to the following:

```
<img src="../pics/process.png" style="border:none; " onclick="Sort();">
```

I can successfully take the user to the results page, but the answers to the form are not stored to my database.

I'm stuck and have no idea how to approach this, any help would be appreciated.

**Here's the code for generating the results**

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
    function Sort() {
        //australia
        var party1= 0;
        var party2= 0;

        if (compass.q1[0].checked == true) {
            party1 += 1;
        } else if (compass.q1[1].checked == true) {
            party2 += 1;
        } else {
            alert("Please answer question 1.");
            return;
        }

        if (compass.q2[0].checked == true) {

            party1 += 1;
        } else if (compass.q2[1].checked == true) {
            party2 += 1;
        } else {
            alert("Please answer question 2.");
            return;
        }

        window.location.href = "./australiacompassresult.php?" + party1+ "&" + party2;
    }
```

`

**Here is my form header and submit button when I can submit the form successfully but fail to load the results page**

```
<form id="compassform" name="compass" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

**Here is the php code to insert the data from the form to my database**
<?php

```
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password", "database");

        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    
            die ("There was an error connecting to the database");
    
        }    
            $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`q1`, `q2`, `q3`, `q4`, `q5`, `q6`, `q7`, `q8`) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['q1'])."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['q2'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['q3'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['q4'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['q5'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['q7'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['q7'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['q8'])."')";
            
            if (mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
                
                echo "";
            }
```

?>

Comment: Can you please show the Javascript and PHP code

Comment: The right way would be to have the form submit directly to the results page:
`<form action="australiacompassresult.php">` and give your checkboxes names and values that you want to submit.

Comment: preventDefault the submit action.

Comment: You have an error in your url: `window.location.href = "./australiacompassresult.php?" + party1+ "&" + party2;` use this: `window.location.href = "./australiacompassresult.php?" + "party1=" + party1+ "&party2=" + party2;` to get `get` params at the requested page.

Comment: Here is the tutorial how to redirect to the desired page after success submission or failure: https://www.bluehost.com/help/article/php-redirect

Answer (score 2):

First, attach a `submit` event listener to the form. After this call retrieve the `event` object and call the `preventDefault()` method to prevent the default behavior of the form submission. After this call the `window.location.href` to guide the user to the relevant page.

eg:

```
document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit",(e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        window.location.href = "./australiacompassresult.php?" + party1+ "&" + party2;
});
```

Comment: The variables are undefined in this answer

Comment: Thanks for this. When I add this, i seem to be able to generate the results, but they're not being inserted into the database. 

If I remove e.preventDefault(), then I can insert the results to my database but it doesn't take the user to the results page. 

I've included the PHP for what i am doing to insert my answers from the form to the database.

Comment: Does the page go the results page and then reload back to the form page?

Comment: No, it appears to just reload the page without ever getting to the results.

Comment: Also, is this supposed to be included in my sort function, or as separate javascript code underneath my form?

Comment: This is supposed to be included in the form submission function